# Calculate $I= \int_{1}^{e}\frac{(1+\ln x)x}{(1+x\ln x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, logarithms

Please help me solve this: (level = high school)
$$
\int_{1}^{e}\frac{(1+\ln x)x}{(1+x\ln x)^2}\,dx
$$

Thanks

Comment: I dont think so bro:
$$
(\frac{1}{1+x\ln x})\prime = -\frac{(1+x\ln x)\prime}{(1+x\ln x)^2}=  -\frac{\ln x - 1}{(1+x\ln x)^2}
$$

Comment: Either you typed the question wrong or a closed form doesn't exist and you have to use approximation methods to find the answer. [See this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28%281%2Bln+x%29x%29%2F%281+%2B+xln%28x%29%29^2+from+1+to+e)

Comment: I am sorry.I'll delete my comment.

Comment: I copied it from my textbook and I am sure that I did not type anything wrong. However I dont know whether the textbook was wrong or not.

Comment: @user161621 Check again and see, indeed, that you typed in the correct integral and if that's not the case and you _haven't_ learned approximation methods then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you book is correct, basically the only thing you can do is integrating by parts, noticing that the derivative of $\Big(1+x\log(x)\Big)$ is $\Big(1+\log(x)\Big)$.

Then, setting $u=x$,$v'=\frac{1+\ln x}{(1+x\ln x)^2}$, you have $u'=1$,$v=-\frac{1}{1+x\ln x}$ and then $$\int\frac{(1+\ln x)x}{(1+x\ln x)^2}\,dx=-\frac{x}{1+x\ln x}+\int\frac{dx}{1+x\ln x}$$ and the problem is, again, that there is no closed form for the last integral.

So, confirming what already said by other participants, either the book is wrong or you must go through numerical evaluations.

What I think is that the problem is instead $$\int_{1}^{e}\frac{(1+\ln x)}{(1+x\ln x)^2}\,dx=\frac{e}{1+e}$$